# Java obfuscator which never gives plain text on decompilation

Tags: java, obfuscation

I have came across many Java obfuscators which just renames the class names and that can be viewed by online java decompilers. But I want a obfuscator which generates output that cannot be decompiled using any tools. ( We can obfuscate the .net projects in such way ).

Please suggest me such java obfuscator ?

Comment: I would not expect such a tool to be possible.  Given Java bytecode, you can always turn it into Java source.

Comment: "We can obfuscate the .net projects in such way" Using what?

Comment: "But I want a obfuscator which generates output that cannot be decompiled using any tools."  Including the Java virtual machine?  Just write a scrambler, then.  Your code won't be stolen and your code won't run.

Comment: We can obfuscate the .net projects in such way? Better say, you did a preventive obfuscator, but not preventive against all deobfuscation tools.

Answer (score 2):

Search for "flow obfuscation".

Decompilation is always possible. However, a lot of decompilers expect bytecode to be generated by regular compilers like javac and have trouble to restore compilable Java sources from flow-obfuscated classes. The results are more often than not so broken that it is hard for a human to recognize the original (Java high-level) control flow. That creates an additional hurdle that can only be overcome by investing more time in bytecode analysis.

Be aware, however, that it's a race: decompilers are also becoming better at this. So you should always test the obfuscated results against all decompilers you can get a hold off.

We've used an obfuscator called "allatori" (together with a second mostly name-based obfuscator) in a project with quite satisfactory results.

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan mentioned flow obfuscation is an easy way to mess with older decompilers. For modern decompilers you're going to have to put in more effort. Heres some features you can search for:

- Synthetic Modifiers *(JD-GUI does not show synthetic members)*
- Opaque Predicates *(Think of this as junk code that can't be resolved statically)*
- String Encryption
- Not sure what it's called but [replacing all invokes with invokedynamics is cruel](https://github.com/licel/indyprotectordemo/blob/master/src/main/java/javaone2015/con7442/indyprotector/MethodIndyProtector.java). Requires Java 8 to run and decompile.

Everything is reversible but it'll make it more of a pain.